# about recursions in a list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

I am having trouble with recursion.  My program here is simple.  It consumes a list of donations and return true if any of the donations on the list is over 2500.

```
(define-struct donation (donor amount))
```

This is my helper

```
;;helper
(define (bad-donations bad-d)
  (cond
    [(number? bad-d) (<= 50 bad-d)]
    [(donation? bad-d) (< 2500 (donation-amount bad-d))]))

(check-expect (bad-donations 51) true)
(check-expect (bad-donations 30) false )
(check-expect (bad-donations 50) true)


(define (any-bad-donations? lod)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) true]
    [(cons? lod)
     (bad-donations (first lod))]
    [else
     (any-bad-donations? (bad-donations   (rest lod)))]))
```

it works fine if i do something like

```
(any-bad-donations? (list (make-donation "Marry" 50000))
```

would should produce True, since its over the limit of 2500.

But if I do

```
(any-bad-donations? (list (make-donation "Marry" 50) (make-donation "Marry 50000))
```

it would give me False, which it shouldn't, since the rest is over 2500. So it should give me true.

What am I doing wrong for the recursion part of my program?

Comment: Your `bad-donations` function checks whether its argument is a number or a donation (so both `(bad-donation 42)` and `(bad-donation (make-donation "Jenny" 8675309))` would be legal calls, but you only have checks for the first type of case.

Comment: Also, `(any-bad-donations? (list (make-donation "Marry" 50) (make-donation "Marry 50000))` wouldn't give you false,  it would give you a syntax error about an unterminated string `"Marry 50000))…"`. Please be sure to include valid code in your questions (unless, of course, the question is about why some code isn't valid).  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems in each of the conditions in the `any-bad-donations?` procedure:

1. If the list is empty, then because there are *no* "bad donations", `false` should be returned
2. You don't have to check if the list is a pair using `cons?`, what you need to do is to check if the current element is a bad donation, if that's the case then you can return `true` immediately, we've found one
3. You're incorrectly advancing the recursion

This should fix the problems, but be careful - there seems to be a conceptual problem in the way you're thinking about recursive solutions:

```
(define (any-bad-donations? lod)
  (cond
    [(empty? lod) false]
    [(bad-donations (first lod)) true]
    [else (any-bad-donations? (rest lod))]))
```

Now the solution works as expected:

```
(any-bad-donations?
 (list (make-donation "Mary" 50000)))
=> #t

(any-bad-donations?
 (list (make-donation "Mary" 50) (make-donation "Mary" 50000)))
=> #t
```